# Copy files with grunt skip source folder

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

There is *source* folder and *publish* folder in the project. I want to copy all files and folders from source to publish.

[image]

Related code from Gruntfiles.js:

```
grunt.initConfig({
        copy: {
          main: {
            files: [
              { src: ['source/**/*'], dest: 'publish/'},
              ]
          }
      }
});

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['copy']);
```

However it copies *source* folder itself and puts in *publish* folder.

[image]

Tried a lot of variations from [grunt-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) documentation and cannot find solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this configuration:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    copy: {
        main: {
            cwd: 'source',
            src: ['**/*'],
            dest: 'publish/',
            expand: true
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only copy some parts of SRC and build the others on the normal flow (SASS, CONCAT, MINIFY plugins), you may choose to:

```
copy: {
  main: {
    files: [
      {expand: true, cwd: '../src/', src: ['images/*'], dest: '../public/images'},
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

The key point above is the CWD which allows you to copy folders as is instead of copying the "src" inside "public".